# How to hide RDLC Table Column if no data is present in all the Rows with Expression?

Tags: rdlc, rdl

I would like to hide the entire column including the header if all the rows under that is null or of no values with expression in an RDLC Report.

I have tried the expression

```
"=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!de_projectactivityidname.Value), True, False)"
```

inside the "Visibility" of the Column property.

I would like to do this without any report parameters.

any help is appreciated.

Vinu

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track, but likely the field is never going to be null/nothing.  Instead, it's likely to be an empty string.

This should work:

```
=IIF((Fields!de_projectactivityidname.Value = ""), True, False)
```